# Need help with a character + double handed staff game rig

Tags: animation, rigging, constraints

I need help with a double handed staff character rig I made for a game project, since I don't know if I've used the best practices for my purpose.
First of all, I am a newbie to complicated (at least for me this one was) game rigs, in fact, I know only the very basics of rigging with blender and I've done some simple rigs in the past. I aim to make fast staff handling animations like shaolin kung fu-style fighting or doing spinning tricks, etc, so I wanted two states per hand, one where it would be the main one that moves the staff, with the other hand following the staff, and one where the hand still moves the staff, exluding on its X axis, which allows the hand to slide along it.
[image: GENERAL PIC OF WHOLE RIG SETUP]

BLEND FILE: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bLLk4UkxJsgNUPbeBwzcfzSFlCD5-QFt/view?usp=sharing

This is for a game character, so I want it to have good integration with Unity, mainly, but I'm also using it for an animation demo reel. I have already used  this character to make 3 animation cycles, idle, walking and running, but I am only now adding the staff weapon. I first adjusted a basic human meta rig to my character, and then generated a rigify rig.

My workflow for the other animations has been simple: posing, keyframing, using interpolation and tweaking graph editor curves. When I was satisfied with my cycle I saved it to the NLA, and then used the Game Rig Tools addon which transforms the rigify animated rig to a rig more suitable for game engines, as far as I know.

Also, I will reuse this rig for every character and it will be using a bunch of very different weapons like maybe bows, knuckle gloves, swords, staff, maybe dual blades?, you get it... So that's why I made a separate rig for the weapon, but I don't really know if this is the best option for exporting it to a game engine. Also, in this case, I guess I'd have to keyframe the staff separately so if I have e.g. staff_attack_1 animation for the character rig, I also have to do staff_attack_1 keyframe animation for the weapong right, right?
But on the other hand, if you tell me that it's better to make the weapong rig part of the character rig, I would have to modify my human meta rig and then create the rigify rig again? Or can I modify the rigify rig directly and add the weapon bones to it?

I am going to try to explain my setup as best as I can, but I will link the blend file and also put screenshots of it. So I have the weapong rig with multiple bones but I am only using the root bone named Bone. Then I have created two empty objects to use as controllers, one for each hand. I have applied a copy transforms constraint of the weapong rig's root bone to each controller so they have the same orientation as the weapon, this way I can use a limit location constraint on the weapong to allow the hands to slide along its X axis. I'll go into more details about that further down.
[image: Controllers and weapon rig isolated]
I have two states for each hand, which are the same but only changing certain relations between them so the main hand changes. Think of it like a chain, that goes on one direction but switching certain constraint influence values it can change to the other direction, allowing either hand to be the main or the one that follows. This is the diagram of it: hand_ik.R bone - hand.R controller - weapon root bone - hand.L controller - hand_ik.L bone
The two states for each hand are: RIGHT/LEFT HAND MAIN (meaning that if it's the right one, then the right hand moves the staff and the left hand follows the staff) and the RIGHT/LEFT HAND SLIDING (meaning that if it's the right one, then it allows the right hand to still move the staff but only on its Z and Y axis, and it slides on the X axis, so along the staff). Here is a list of what types of constraints each object/bone has and what influence they have in each state.

•character hand ik.R - CHILD OF Weapon root bone (for left hand main state) and CHILD OF hand.R controller (for sliding state).

[image: hand ik.R constraints]

•hand.R controller - CHILD OF Weapon root bone (for left hand main state) and CHILD OF DEF-hand.R bone (for right hand main state).

[image: hand.R controller constraints]

•staff root - LIMIT LOCATION, X axis maximum 5m, owner custom space, object hand.R controller (for right hand sliding state) and CHILD OF DEF-hand.R bone (for right hand main state) ALSO I duplicated each of these and changed the L and R accordingly to achieve the same but for the left hand.

[image: weapon root bone constraints]

•hand.L controller - same as R controller but changing the bone to L.

[image: hand.L controller constraints]

•character hand ik.L - same as R hand IK but changing the controller to L.

[image: hand ik.L constraints]

*Note: the reason for using both child of and limit location on the root bone is because using only child of doesn't allow me to animate the sliding on the weapon x axis, since the weapon will follow, as far as I know there is no way in doing that only with this constraint but let me know if I'm wrong.
Also, on one of the controllers and staff CHILD OF constraints I've used the DEF-hand.L/R bones as parents since I think that's the bone that counts when animating a rig, but also let me know if I'm wrong or if this has 0 impact in the result I aim for.

RIGHT HAND MAIN state:

•character hand ik.R - both constraints to 0 influence

•hand.R controller - right hand main 1 influence, the rest at 0

•staff root - right hand main 1 influence, the rest at 0

•hand.L controller - right hand main 1 influence, the rest at 0

•character hand ik.L - right hand main 1 influence, the rest at 0

RIGHT HAND SLIDING ON STAFF's X AXIS state:

•character hand ik.R - sliding constraint to 1 influence, the rest at 0

•hand.R controller - both constraints to 0

•staff root - right hand sliding 1 influence, the rest at 0

•hand.L controller - right hand main 1 influence, the rest at 0

•character hand ik.L - right hand main 1 influence, the rest at 0

And to achieve the same but for the left side, just invert the pertinent constraints letters or influence.
I know it's been a rather long post but I hope someone has some insight on how I can make this better since for every keyframe I also have to go to each element of the chain and keyframe it, because autokeyframe doesn't work when the element has been moved by constraints. It is also tedious when having to change between states, because of having to navigate to each element's constraints window and changing the values. And since I don't know python to write a script for this, I'm hoping someone can give me a better solution.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.